# Efficient way to compare time in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

How do you compare just the time element of a TIMESTAMP column in Redshift?
The closest way I found is to use EXTRACT multiple times for the HOUR, MINUTE and SECOND elements and join them together but it seems inefficient. I also considered a plpythonu UDF.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in postgres it would be `postgres=# select now()::timestamp::time - '2001.09.01 09:00'::timestamp::time as diff;
       diff
------------------
 -00:50:56.267417
(1 row)`

Comment: @VaoTsun Unfortunately it doesn't work in Redshift. I get the following error: 
ERROR: 0A000: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html - yeah - just read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I wrote a simple UDF in plpythonu to suit specific need:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compare_time(timestamp1_ TIMESTAMP, timestamp2_ TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
IMMUTABLE AS $$
import datetime

*start = datetime.time(timestamp1*.hour, timestamp1_.minute, timestamp1_.second)
*end = datetime.time(timestamp2*.hour, timestamp2_.minute, timestamp2_.second)

if _start <= _end:
    return True
return False

$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;